# returning another function in get(), why can't just invoke it instead of add the '()'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  // Getter
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  // Method
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

console.log(square.area); // 100
```

For the above code, in order to return the result of calcArea(), why does it need to add the 'return' key word in get area(). Can it just be invoked like

```
get area(){
this.calcArea();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Because then accessing `area` wouldn't return anything?

Comment: The getter won't return anything and thus you won't "get anything back *in return*".

Comment: Some programming languages automatically return the last evaluated value from a function. JavaScript doesn't (except for single-statement fat arrow functions).

Answer (score 2):

This may sounds ridiculously simple, but: *because otherwise it won't return anything*.

`this.calcArea()` calls the function `calcArea`, and if that function `return`s something, it `return`s *to its caller*, i.e. to `area`. But if `area` isn't doing anything with the value, then it simply gets discarded.

Look at it like this: it doesn't matter what a function you're calling does, that will never influence what your current function does. There's no `return` in `area`, so that function doesn't `return` anything. It doesn't matter what any function you're calling from `area` does, it won't make `area` `return` anything unless `area` explicitly has a `return` statement.

In yet other words, what would you expect this to do:

```
get area() {
  this.calcArea();
  return 42;
}
```

It wouldn't make sense for it to return anything other than `42`. If you take out that `return 42` statement, why would you expect this to return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the `area()` function into several lines:

```
  get area() {
    let a = this.calcArea();
    return a;
  }
```

Here we store the result returned by `this.calcArea()` in a variable named `a`. Then we return the value in that variable. The original code is just a shorthand for this longer version.

Comment: Note to self: "several" now means "at least 2" :P